# Creating multilevel-WBS level lists in google sheets? Task 1.1, Sub task 1.1.1 with arrayFormula

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I need help to build WBS (Work Breakdown Structure) Like Following

| Level | WBS 1 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1.1 |
| 3 | 1.1.1 |
| 4 | 1.1.1.1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 2.1 |
| 3 | 2.1.1 |
| 3 | 2.1.2 |
| 4 | 2.1.2.1 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 3.1 |
| 3 | 3.1.1 |
| 3 | 3.1.2 |
| 1 | 4 |
| 2 | 4.1 |
| 3 | 4.1.1 |
| 4 | 4.1.1.1 |
| 1 | 5 |

These Formula worked for me but not as ArryFormula

```
 - First formula:
=IF(A4="","",if(A4="0",1,IF(A4>OFFSET(A4,-1,0,1,1),
IF(OFFSET(B4,-1,0,1,1)="","1",OFFSET(B4,-1,0,1,1))&REPT(".1",A4-MAX(OFFSET(A4,-1,0,1,1),1)),
IF(ISERROR(FIND(".",OFFSET(B4,-1,0,1,1))),REPT("1.",A4-1)&IFERROR(VALUE(OFFSET(B4,-1,0,1,1))+1,"1"),
IF(A4=1,"",IFERROR(LEFT(OFFSET(B4,-1,0,1,1),FIND("^",SUBSTITUTE(OFFSET(B4,-1,0,1,1),".","^",A4-1))),""))&VALUE(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(OFFSET(B4,-1,0,1,1),".",REPT(" ",LEN(OFFSET(B4,-1,0,1,1)))),(A4-1)*LEN(OFFSET(B4,-1,0,1,1))+1,LEN(OFFSET(B4,-1,0,1,1)))))+1))))
 - Second formula
=IF(A4="","",if(A4="0",1,IF(A4>A3,IF(E3="","1",E3)&REPT(".1",A4-MAX(A3,1)),
IF(ISERROR(FIND(".",E3)),REPT("1.",A4-1)&IFERROR(VALUE(E3)+1,"1"),IF(A4=1,"",
IFERROR(LEFT(E3,FIND("^",SUBSTITUTE(E3,".","^",A4-1))),""))&VALUE(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(E3,".",REPT(" ",LEN(E3))),(A4-1)*LEN(E3)+1,LEN(E3))))+1))))
```

I have tried:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ROW(A3:A)=3,"WBS ID 1", IF(A3:A="","",if(A3:A="0",1,IF(A3:A>OFFSET(A4:A,-1,0,1,1),
IF(OFFSET(C3:C,-1,0,1,1)="","1",OFFSET(C3:C,-1,0,1,1))&REPT(".1",A3:A-MAX(OFFSET(A3:A,-1,0,1,1),1)),
IF(ISERROR(FIND(".",OFFSET(C3:C,-1,0,1,1))), REPT("1.",A3:A-1)&IFERROR(VALUE(OFFSET(C3:C,-1,0,1,1))+1,"1"),
IF(A3:A=1,"",IFERROR(LEFT(OFFSET(C3:C,-1,0,1,1),FIND("^",SUBSTITUTE(OFFSET(C3:C,-1,0,1,1),".","^",A3:A-1))),""))&VALUE(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(OFFSET(C3:C,-1,0,1,1),".",REPT(" ",LEN(OFFSET(C3:C,-1,0,1,1)))),(A3:A-1)*LEN(OFFSET(C3:C,-1,0,1,1))+1,LEN(OFFSET(C3:C,-1,0,1,1)))))+1))))))
```

but it returns:

```
1
1.1
1.1.1
1.1.1.1
1
1.1
1.1.1
```

Here's the link to [WBS Google Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1tx23gAeJEZr31o9qvrcXqkqNI824GVN2cL4Eu9QMFbY/edit?usp=sharing).

Here's the image

[image]

Comment: how many levels you will have?

Comment: @player0 up to 5 level

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there should be a better solution than this tho...

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A4:A="",,IFERROR(VLOOKUP(ROW(A4:A),IF(IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)<>"",{ROW(A4:A),IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)}),2,1)&IF(A4:A>1,VLOOKUP(ROW(A4:A),IF(IF(A4:A=2,"."&COUNTIFS(VLOOKUP(ROW(A4:A),IF(IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)<>"",{ROW(A4:A),IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)}),2,1)&A4:A,VLOOKUP(ROW(A4:A),IF(IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)<>"",{ROW(A4:A),IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)}),2,1)&A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)<>"",{ROW(A4:A),IF(A4:A=2,"."&COUNTIFS(VLOOKUP(ROW(A4:A),IF(IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)<>"",{ROW(A4:A),IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)}),2,1)&A4:A,VLOOKUP(ROW(A4:A),IF(IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)<>"",{ROW(A4:A),IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)}),2,1)&A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)}),2,1),)&IF(A4:A>2,VLOOKUP(ROW(A4:A),IF(IF(A4:A=3,"."&COUNTIFS(VLOOKUP(ROW(A4:A),IF(IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)<>"",{ROW(A4:A),IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)}),2,1)&IF(A4:A>1,VLOOKUP(ROW(A4:A),IF(IF(A4:A=2,"."&COUNTIFS(VLOOKUP(ROW(A4:A),IF(IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)<>"",{ROW(A4:A),IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)}),2,1)&A4:A,VLOOKUP(ROW(A4:A),IF(IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)<>"",{ROW(A4:A),IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)}),2,1)&A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)<>"",{ROW(A4:A),IF(A4:A=2,"."&COUNTIFS(VLOOKUP(ROW(A4:A),IF(IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)<>"",{ROW(A4:A),IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)}),2,1)&A4:A,VLOOKUP(ROW(A4:A),IF(IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)<>"",{ROW(A4:A),IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)}),2,1)&A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)}),2,1),)&A4:A,VLOOKUP(ROW(A4:A),IF(IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)<>"",{ROW(A4:A),IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)}),2,1)&IF(A4:A>1,VLOOKUP(ROW(A4:A),IF(IF(A4:A=2,"."&COUNTIFS(VLOOKUP(ROW(A4:A),IF(IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)<>"",{ROW(A4:A),IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)}),2,1)&A4:A,VLOOKUP(ROW(A4:A),IF(IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)<>"",{ROW(A4:A),IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)}),2,1)&A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)<>"",{ROW(A4:A),IF(A4:A=2,"."&COUNTIFS(VLOOKUP(ROW(A4:A),IF(IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)<>"",{ROW(A4:A),IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)}),2,1)&A4:A,VLOOKUP(ROW(A4:A),IF(IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)<>"",{ROW(A4:A),IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)}),2,1)&A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)}),2,1),)&A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)<>"",{ROW(A4:A),IF(A4:A=3,"."&COUNTIFS(VLOOKUP(ROW(A4:A),IF(IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)<>"",{ROW(A4:A),IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)}),2,1)&IF(A4:A>1,VLOOKUP(ROW(A4:A),IF(IF(A4:A=2,"."&COUNTIFS(VLOOKUP(ROW(A4:A),IF(IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)<>"",{ROW(A4:A),IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)}),2,1)&A4:A,VLOOKUP(ROW(A4:A),IF(IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)<>"",{ROW(A4:A),IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)}),2,1)&A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)<>"",{ROW(A4:A),IF(A4:A=2,"."&COUNTIFS(VLOOKUP(ROW(A4:A),IF(IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)<>"",{ROW(A4:A),IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)}),2,1)&A4:A,VLOOKUP(ROW(A4:A),IF(IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)<>"",{ROW(A4:A),IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)}),2,1)&A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)}),2,1),)&A4:A,VLOOKUP(ROW(A4:A),IF(IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)<>"",{ROW(A4:A),IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)}),2,1)&IF(A4:A>1,VLOOKUP(ROW(A4:A),IF(IF(A4:A=2,"."&COUNTIFS(VLOOKUP(ROW(A4:A),IF(IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)<>"",{ROW(A4:A),IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)}),2,1)&A4:A,VLOOKUP(ROW(A4:A),IF(IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)<>"",{ROW(A4:A),IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)}),2,1)&A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)<>"",{ROW(A4:A),IF(A4:A=2,"."&COUNTIFS(VLOOKUP(ROW(A4:A),IF(IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)<>"",{ROW(A4:A),IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)}),2,1)&A4:A,VLOOKUP(ROW(A4:A),IF(IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)<>"",{ROW(A4:A),IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)}),2,1)&A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)}),2,1),)&A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)}),2,1),)&IF(A4:A>3,VLOOKUP(ROW(A4:A),IF(IF(A4:A=4,"."&COUNTIFS(VLOOKUP(ROW(A4:A),IF(IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)<>"",{ROW(A4:A),IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)}),2,1)&IF(A4:A>1,VLOOKUP(ROW(A4:A),IF(IF(A4:A=2,"."&COUNTIFS(VLOOKUP(ROW(A4:A),IF(IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)<>"",{ROW(A4:A),IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)}),2,1)&A4:A,VLOOKUP(ROW(A4:A),IF(IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)<>"",{ROW(A4:A),IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)}),2,1)&A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)<>"",{ROW(A4:A),IF(A4:A=2,"."&COUNTIFS(VLOOKUP(ROW(A4:A),IF(IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)<>"",{ROW(A4:A),IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)}),2,1)&A4:A,VLOOKUP(ROW(A4:A),IF(IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)<>"",{ROW(A4:A),IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)}),2,1)&A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)}),2,1),)&IF(A4:A>2,VLOOKUP(ROW(A4:A),IF(IF(A4:A=3,"."&COUNTIFS(VLOOKUP(ROW(A4:A),IF(IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)<>"",{ROW(A4:A),IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)}),2,1)&IF(A4:A>1,VLOOKUP(ROW(A4:A),IF(IF(A4:A=2,"."&COUNTIFS(VLOOKUP(ROW(A4:A),IF(IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)<>"",{ROW(A4:A),IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)}),2,1)&A4:A,VLOOKUP(ROW(A4:A),IF(IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)<>"",{ROW(A4:A),IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)}),2,1)&A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)<>"",{ROW(A4:A),IF(A4:A=2,"."&COUNTIFS(VLOOKUP(ROW(A4:A),IF(IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)<>"",{ROW(A4:A),IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)}),2,1)&A4:A,VLOOKUP(ROW(A4:A),IF(IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)<>"",{ROW(A4:A),IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)}),2,1)&A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)}),2,1),)&A4:A,VLOOKUP(ROW(A4:A),IF(IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)<>"",{ROW(A4:A),IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)}),2,1)&IF(A4:A>1,VLOOKUP(ROW(A4:A),IF(IF(A4:A=2,"."&COUNTIFS(VLOOKUP(ROW(A4:A),IF(IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)<>"",{ROW(A4:A),IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)}),2,1)&A4:A,VLOOKUP(ROW(A4:A),IF(IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)<>"",{ROW(A4:A),IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)}),2,1)&A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)<>"",{ROW(A4:A),IF(A4:A=2,"."&COUNTIFS(VLOOKUP(ROW(A4:A),IF(IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)<>"",{ROW(A4:A),IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)}),2,1)&A4:A,VLOOKUP(ROW(A4:A),IF(IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)<>"",{ROW(A4:A),IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)}),2,1)&A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)}),2,1),)&A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)<>"",{ROW(A4:A),IF(A4:A=3,"."&COUNTIFS(VLOOKUP(ROW(A4:A),IF(IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)<>"",{ROW(A4:A),IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)}),2,1)&IF(A4:A>1,VLOOKUP(ROW(A4:A),IF(IF(A4:A=2,"."&COUNTIFS(VLOOKUP(ROW(A4:A),IF(IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)<>"",{ROW(A4:A),IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)}),2,1)&A4:A,VLOOKUP(ROW(A4:A),IF(IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)<>"",{ROW(A4:A),IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)}),2,1)&A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)<>"",{ROW(A4:A),IF(A4:A=2,"."&COUNTIFS(VLOOKUP(ROW(A4:A),IF(IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)<>"",{ROW(A4:A),IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)}),2,1)&A4:A,VLOOKUP(ROW(A4:A),IF(IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)<>"",{ROW(A4:A),IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)}),2,1)&A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)}),2,1),)&A4:A,VLOOKUP(ROW(A4:A),IF(IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)<>"",{ROW(A4:A),IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)}),2,1)&IF(A4:A>1,VLOOKUP(ROW(A4:A),IF(IF(A4:A=2,"."&COUNTIFS(VLOOKUP(ROW(A4:A),IF(IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)<>"",{ROW(A4:A),IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)}),2,1)&A4:A,VLOOKUP(ROW(A4:A),IF(IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)<>"",{ROW(A4:A),IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)}),2,1)&A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)<>"",{ROW(A4:A),IF(A4:A=2,"."&COUNTIFS(VLOOKUP(ROW(A4:A),IF(IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)<>"",{ROW(A4:A),IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)}),2,1)&A4:A,VLOOKUP(ROW(A4:A),IF(IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)<>"",{ROW(A4:A),IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)}),2,1)&A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)}),2,1),)&A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)}),2,1),)&A4:A,VLOOKUP(ROW(A4:A),IF(IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)<>"",{ROW(A4:A),IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)}),2,1)&IF(A4:A>1,VLOOKUP(ROW(A4:A),IF(IF(A4:A=2,"."&COUNTIFS(VLOOKUP(ROW(A4:A),IF(IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)<>"",{ROW(A4:A),IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)}),2,1)&A4:A,VLOOKUP(ROW(A4:A),IF(IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)<>"",{ROW(A4:A),IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)}),2,1)&A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)<>"",{ROW(A4:A),IF(A4:A=2,"."&COUNTIFS(VLOOKUP(ROW(A4:A),IF(IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)<>"",{ROW(A4:A),IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)}),2,1)&A4:A,VLOOKUP(ROW(A4:A),IF(IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)<>"",{ROW(A4:A),IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)}),2,1)&A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)}),2,1),)&IF(A4:A>2,VLOOKUP(ROW(A4:A),IF(IF(A4:A=3,"."&COUNTIFS(VLOOKUP(ROW(A4:A),IF(IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)<>"",{ROW(A4:A),IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)}),2,1)&IF(A4:A>1,VLOOKUP(ROW(A4:A),IF(IF(A4:A=2,"."&COUNTIFS(VLOOKUP(ROW(A4:A),IF(IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)<>"",{ROW(A4:A),IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)}),2,1)&A4:A,VLOOKUP(ROW(A4:A),IF(IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)<>"",{ROW(A4:A),IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)}),2,1)&A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)<>"",{ROW(A4:A),IF(A4:A=2,"."&COUNTIFS(VLOOKUP(ROW(A4:A),IF(IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)<>"",{ROW(A4:A),IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)}),2,1)&A4:A,VLOOKUP(ROW(A4:A),IF(IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)<>"",{ROW(A4:A),IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)}),2,1)&A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)}),2,1),)&A4:A,VLOOKUP(ROW(A4:A),IF(IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)<>"",{ROW(A4:A),IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)}),2,1)&IF(A4:A>1,VLOOKUP(ROW(A4:A),IF(IF(A4:A=2,"."&COUNTIFS(VLOOKUP(ROW(A4:A),IF(IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)<>"",{ROW(A4:A),IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)}),2,1)&A4:A,VLOOKUP(ROW(A4:A),IF(IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)<>"",{ROW(A4:A),IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)}),2,1)&A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)<>"",{ROW(A4:A),IF(A4:A=2,"."&COUNTIFS(VLOOKUP(ROW(A4:A),IF(IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)<>"",{ROW(A4:A),IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)}),2,1)&A4:A,VLOOKUP(ROW(A4:A),IF(IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)<>"",{ROW(A4:A),IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)}),2,1)&A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)}),2,1),)&A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)<>"",{ROW(A4:A),IF(A4:A=3,"."&COUNTIFS(VLOOKUP(ROW(A4:A),IF(IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)<>"",{ROW(A4:A),IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)}),2,1)&IF(A4:A>1,VLOOKUP(ROW(A4:A),IF(IF(A4:A=2,"."&COUNTIFS(VLOOKUP(ROW(A4:A),IF(IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)<>"",{ROW(A4:A),IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)}),2,1)&A4:A,VLOOKUP(ROW(A4:A),IF(IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)<>"",{ROW(A4:A),IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)}),2,1)&A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)<>"",{ROW(A4:A),IF(A4:A=2,"."&COUNTIFS(VLOOKUP(ROW(A4:A),IF(IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)<>"",{ROW(A4:A),IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)}),2,1)&A4:A,VLOOKUP(ROW(A4:A),IF(IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)<>"",{ROW(A4:A),IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)}),2,1)&A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)}),2,1),)&A4:A,VLOOKUP(ROW(A4:A),IF(IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)<>"",{ROW(A4:A),IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)}),2,1)&IF(A4:A>1,VLOOKUP(ROW(A4:A),IF(IF(A4:A=2,"."&COUNTIFS(VLOOKUP(ROW(A4:A),IF(IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)<>"",{ROW(A4:A),IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)}),2,1)&A4:A,VLOOKUP(ROW(A4:A),IF(IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)<>"",{ROW(A4:A),IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)}),2,1)&A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)<>"",{ROW(A4:A),IF(A4:A=2,"."&COUNTIFS(VLOOKUP(ROW(A4:A),IF(IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)<>"",{ROW(A4:A),IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)}),2,1)&A4:A,VLOOKUP(ROW(A4:A),IF(IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)<>"",{ROW(A4:A),IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)}),2,1)&A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)}),2,1),)&A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)}),2,1),)&A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)<>"",{ROW(A4:A),IF(A4:A=4,"."&COUNTIFS(VLOOKUP(ROW(A4:A),IF(IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)<>"",{ROW(A4:A),IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)}),2,1)&IF(A4:A>1,VLOOKUP(ROW(A4:A),IF(IF(A4:A=2,"."&COUNTIFS(VLOOKUP(ROW(A4:A),IF(IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)<>"",{ROW(A4:A),IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)}),2,1)&A4:A,VLOOKUP(ROW(A4:A),IF(IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)<>"",{ROW(A4:A),IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)}),2,1)&A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)<>"",{ROW(A4:A),IF(A4:A=2,"."&COUNTIFS(VLOOKUP(ROW(A4:A),IF(IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)<>"",{ROW(A4:A),IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)}),2,1)&A4:A,VLOOKUP(ROW(A4:A),IF(IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)<>"",{ROW(A4:A),IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)}),2,1)&A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)}),2,1),)&IF(A4:A>2,VLOOKUP(ROW(A4:A),IF(IF(A4:A=3,"."&COUNTIFS(VLOOKUP(ROW(A4:A),IF(IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)<>"",{ROW(A4:A),IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)}),2,1)&IF(A4:A>1,VLOOKUP(ROW(A4:A),IF(IF(A4:A=2,"."&COUNTIFS(VLOOKUP(ROW(A4:A),IF(IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)<>"",{ROW(A4:A),IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)}),2,1)&A4:A,VLOOKUP(ROW(A4:A),IF(IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)<>"",{ROW(A4:A),IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)}),2,1)&A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)<>"",{ROW(A4:A),IF(A4:A=2,"."&COUNTIFS(VLOOKUP(ROW(A4:A),IF(IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)<>"",{ROW(A4:A),IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)}),2,1)&A4:A,VLOOKUP(ROW(A4:A),IF(IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)<>"",{ROW(A4:A),IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)}),2,1)&A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)}),2,1),)&A4:A,VLOOKUP(ROW(A4:A),IF(IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)<>"",{ROW(A4:A),IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)}),2,1)&IF(A4:A>1,VLOOKUP(ROW(A4:A),IF(IF(A4:A=2,"."&COUNTIFS(VLOOKUP(ROW(A4:A),IF(IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)<>"",{ROW(A4:A),IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)}),2,1)&A4:A,VLOOKUP(ROW(A4:A),IF(IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)<>"",{ROW(A4:A),IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)}),2,1)&A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)<>"",{ROW(A4:A),IF(A4:A=2,"."&COUNTIFS(VLOOKUP(ROW(A4:A),IF(IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)<>"",{ROW(A4:A),IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)}),2,1)&A4:A,VLOOKUP(ROW(A4:A),IF(IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)<>"",{ROW(A4:A),IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)}),2,1)&A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)}),2,1),)&A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)<>"",{ROW(A4:A),IF(A4:A=3,"."&COUNTIFS(VLOOKUP(ROW(A4:A),IF(IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)<>"",{ROW(A4:A),IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)}),2,1)&IF(A4:A>1,VLOOKUP(ROW(A4:A),IF(IF(A4:A=2,"."&COUNTIFS(VLOOKUP(ROW(A4:A),IF(IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)<>"",{ROW(A4:A),IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)}),2,1)&A4:A,VLOOKUP(ROW(A4:A),IF(IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)<>"",{ROW(A4:A),IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)}),2,1)&A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)<>"",{ROW(A4:A),IF(A4:A=2,"."&COUNTIFS(VLOOKUP(ROW(A4:A),IF(IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)<>"",{ROW(A4:A),IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)}),2,1)&A4:A,VLOOKUP(ROW(A4:A),IF(IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)<>"",{ROW(A4:A),IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)}),2,1)&A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)}),2,1),)&A4:A,VLOOKUP(ROW(A4:A),IF(IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)<>"",{ROW(A4:A),IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)}),2,1)&IF(A4:A>1,VLOOKUP(ROW(A4:A),IF(IF(A4:A=2,"."&COUNTIFS(VLOOKUP(ROW(A4:A),IF(IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)<>"",{ROW(A4:A),IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)}),2,1)&A4:A,VLOOKUP(ROW(A4:A),IF(IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)<>"",{ROW(A4:A),IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)}),2,1)&A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)<>"",{ROW(A4:A),IF(A4:A=2,"."&COUNTIFS(VLOOKUP(ROW(A4:A),IF(IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)<>"",{ROW(A4:A),IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)}),2,1)&A4:A,VLOOKUP(ROW(A4:A),IF(IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)<>"",{ROW(A4:A),IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)}),2,1)&A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)}),2,1),)&A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)}),2,1),)&A4:A,VLOOKUP(ROW(A4:A),IF(IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)<>"",{ROW(A4:A),IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)}),2,1)&IF(A4:A>1,VLOOKUP(ROW(A4:A),IF(IF(A4:A=2,"."&COUNTIFS(VLOOKUP(ROW(A4:A),IF(IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)<>"",{ROW(A4:A),IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)}),2,1)&A4:A,VLOOKUP(ROW(A4:A),IF(IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)<>"",{ROW(A4:A),IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)}),2,1)&A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)<>"",{ROW(A4:A),IF(A4:A=2,"."&COUNTIFS(VLOOKUP(ROW(A4:A),IF(IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)<>"",{ROW(A4:A),IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)}),2,1)&A4:A,VLOOKUP(ROW(A4:A),IF(IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)<>"",{ROW(A4:A),IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)}),2,1)&A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)}),2,1),)&IF(A4:A>2,VLOOKUP(ROW(A4:A),IF(IF(A4:A=3,"."&COUNTIFS(VLOOKUP(ROW(A4:A),IF(IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)<>"",{ROW(A4:A),IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)}),2,1)&IF(A4:A>1,VLOOKUP(ROW(A4:A),IF(IF(A4:A=2,"."&COUNTIFS(VLOOKUP(ROW(A4:A),IF(IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)<>"",{ROW(A4:A),IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)}),2,1)&A4:A,VLOOKUP(ROW(A4:A),IF(IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)<>"",{ROW(A4:A),IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)}),2,1)&A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)<>"",{ROW(A4:A),IF(A4:A=2,"."&COUNTIFS(VLOOKUP(ROW(A4:A),IF(IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)<>"",{ROW(A4:A),IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)}),2,1)&A4:A,VLOOKUP(ROW(A4:A),IF(IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)<>"",{ROW(A4:A),IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)}),2,1)&A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)}),2,1),)&A4:A,VLOOKUP(ROW(A4:A),IF(IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)<>"",{ROW(A4:A),IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)}),2,1)&IF(A4:A>1,VLOOKUP(ROW(A4:A),IF(IF(A4:A=2,"."&COUNTIFS(VLOOKUP(ROW(A4:A),IF(IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)<>"",{ROW(A4:A),IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)}),2,1)&A4:A,VLOOKUP(ROW(A4:A),IF(IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)<>"",{ROW(A4:A),IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)}),2,1)&A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)<>"",{ROW(A4:A),IF(A4:A=2,"."&COUNTIFS(VLOOKUP(ROW(A4:A),IF(IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)<>"",{ROW(A4:A),IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)}),2,1)&A4:A,VLOOKUP(ROW(A4:A),IF(IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)<>"",{ROW(A4:A),IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)}),2,1)&A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)}),2,1),)&A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)<>"",{ROW(A4:A),IF(A4:A=3,"."&COUNTIFS(VLOOKUP(ROW(A4:A),IF(IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)<>"",{ROW(A4:A),IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)}),2,1)&IF(A4:A>1,VLOOKUP(ROW(A4:A),IF(IF(A4:A=2,"."&COUNTIFS(VLOOKUP(ROW(A4:A),IF(IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)<>"",{ROW(A4:A),IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)}),2,1)&A4:A,VLOOKUP(ROW(A4:A),IF(IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)<>"",{ROW(A4:A),IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)}),2,1)&A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)<>"",{ROW(A4:A),IF(A4:A=2,"."&COUNTIFS(VLOOKUP(ROW(A4:A),IF(IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)<>"",{ROW(A4:A),IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)}),2,1)&A4:A,VLOOKUP(ROW(A4:A),IF(IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)<>"",{ROW(A4:A),IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)}),2,1)&A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)}),2,1),)&A4:A,VLOOKUP(ROW(A4:A),IF(IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)<>"",{ROW(A4:A),IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)}),2,1)&IF(A4:A>1,VLOOKUP(ROW(A4:A),IF(IF(A4:A=2,"."&COUNTIFS(VLOOKUP(ROW(A4:A),IF(IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)<>"",{ROW(A4:A),IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)}),2,1)&A4:A,VLOOKUP(ROW(A4:A),IF(IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)<>"",{ROW(A4:A),IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)}),2,1)&A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)<>"",{ROW(A4:A),IF(A4:A=2,"."&COUNTIFS(VLOOKUP(ROW(A4:A),IF(IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)<>"",{ROW(A4:A),IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)}),2,1)&A4:A,VLOOKUP(ROW(A4:A),IF(IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)<>"",{ROW(A4:A),IF(A4:A=1,COUNTIFS(A4:A,A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)}),2,1)&A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)}),2,1),)&A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)}),2,1),)&A4:A,ROW(A4:A),"<="&ROW(A4:A)),)}),2,1),))))
```

[image]

---

### note that this may crash your sheet so test it first on a copy!!

for level 5 you will need to insert this formula via <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> dialog box where you replace something in the cell with this formula:

formula here because we hit even SO characters limit: **https://pastebin.com/raw/zix34daD**

[image]

[image]

works well if you paste that formula into cell and never ever touch that cell again

Comment: Would you please add the fifth level, as it only worked for the fourth level. Thank you